# Have two CustomMessageBoxes in the same project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows.Forms application. It has a menubar, which has a button. When I click that button another Form opens up (a "CustomMessageBox").

This CustomMessageBox has a ListView, a few RichTextBoxes, a few labels and a few buttons. It's pretty much just a form for adding data to a list. All well and good, working as intended.

Here's the code for the current CustomMessageBox:

```cs
namespace CustomMessageBoxNS {
    public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form {
        static Dictionary<string, string> currentDictionary;
        static CustomMessageBox MyBox;
        static ListView macroList;
        static Form thisWindow;
        static Label firstLabel;
        static Label secondLabel;

        public CustomMessageBox() {
            InitializeComponent();

            macroList = cmb_lb_macroList;
            firstLabel = cmb_lbl_name;
            secondLabel = cmb_lbl_action;
            thisWindow = this;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> Show(Dictionary<string, string> inData, string title, string label1, string label2) {
            MyBox = new CustomMessageBox();
            currentDictionary = inData;

            thisWindow.Text = title;
            firstLabel.Text = label1;
            secondLabel.Text = label2;

            updateListBox();
            MyBox.ShowDialog();

            return currentDictionary;
        }

    //Plus a whole bunch of other methods which aren't relevant for my question.
    }
}
```

The CustomMessageBox is used like this:

```cs
macroDictionary = CustomMessageBox.Show(macroDictionary, "Edit Macros", "Name:", "Macro:");
```

Doing that shows the CustomMessageBox like a normal MessageBox, nothing strange.

Now to my issue:
I wanted to create another CustomMessageBox - which looks completely different from the current one (other Controls.) I tried: Add -> Existing Item -> Browse to my CustomMessageBox project -> choose the class file. But when I imported it like that I got a whole bunch of errors. Having "two of the same" made them clash.

It's difficult to describe it when I don't know what cases it. My guess is that I can't have two classes in the same project with the same "public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form"

I get a whole bunch of errors, but the most telling one is: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties."

Now I wonder how I can fix so I can have "two of the same, but different"?

Comment: Just name the classes differently?

Comment: Give the new class another name or put it in a different namespace.

Comment: When you have two things that are different it's generally expected that you'd give them different names.

Comment: When I first started I tried renaming one of the classes, but there was so many errors I got scared and undid all the changes and removed the second class. I tried again now, and it seems to work.

However, I get this message:
"The designer has fixed inconsistent type names in a partial class.  The partial class name 'CustomMessageBoxNS.CustomMessageBox' has been changed to 'CustomMessageBoxNS_QuickEdit.QuickEdit'."
Not sure what it means about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the new class another name or put it in a different namespace.

Two classes that reside in the same namespace of the same assembly cannot have the same name obviously.

If you decide to put the new class in a different namespace:

```
namespace NewNamespace {
    public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form {
...
```

...you could reference it using a fully qualified name:

```
NewNamespace.CustomMessageBox.Show(...);
```

...or by adding a using directive at the top of the code file in which you use it:

```
using NewNamespace;
```

But it would probably make most sense to give the new class a unique name after all.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to succesfully rename both Classes to something more suitable. It took a while before the errors went away, even after renaming the classes. I just had to be more patient.